# CDK: How to deploy all resources of the entire project inside single stack?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am deploying a `codepipeline pipeline` using CDK. There are lots of dependent resources for example lambdas, s3 bucket.

**I want to deploy all resources of this pipeline as part of single stack**.

Note: There is no error, pipeline runs well no issues with cloudformation but I will be deploying resources for dev,stg and prod. Right now with my current implementation for dev there are around 15 stacks.

Here is my project structure

**bin/main.ts - entry point**

```
new Pipeline(app, `single-stack-pipeline`, {
  //props....
})
```

**stacks/codepipeline.ts**

```
export class Pipeline extends cdk.Stack {

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: PipelineProps) {

    super(scope, id, props);

// this resource ( topic) results in different stack

    const manualApprovalNotification = new SnsTopic(this, ' manual-approval-sns-topic', {
      topicName: setResourceName(this, 'topic', 'name-of-topic', props.pipelineEnv),
    })

// this resource is deployed as part of same stack single-stack-pipeline

const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'code-pipeline', {
      pipelineName: setResourceName(this, 'pipeline', 'pipeline-name', props.pipelineEnv),
      crossAccountKeys: false,
      artifactBucket: xxxxx,

      stages: [

        {
          stageName: 'Source',
          actions: [sourceAction]
        },

        {
          stageName: 'Plan',
          actions: [xxxxx]
        },

        {
          stageName: 'Approval',
          actions: [manualApprovalAction]
        },

        {
          stageName: 'Deploy',
          actions: [xxxxxxx]
        }

      ]
    })

}
```

Ofcourse to manage my code in a Better way I have created a construct for sns topic

**constructs/sns-topic.ts**

```
export class SnsTopic extends cdk.Stack {
    public readonly topic: sns.Topic;

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: SnsTopicProps) {

        super(scope, id, props);

        this.topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'Topic', {
            topicName: props.topicName,
        });
    }
}
```

Current cloudformation list of stacks :

- single-stack-pipeline
- manualApprovalNotificationTopic-1233434

TL;DR

**I want to include all resources inside single stack:  single-stack-pipeline**

Comment: You created a Stack, not a construct. Try extending `Construct` instead. I'm assuming this is a toy example, since this construct does not provide any functionality/abstraction over the default `Topic` construct. If it's a real example - just use `Topic` directly instead.

Comment: `Try extending Construct instead.` how should I do this?

`just use Topic directly instead. `. I am creating at least 5 topics and same goes for other resources. I am directly use `Topic` everything would clutter inside the single file. That was the whole idea to seperate resources.

Can you provide me an example, feel free to use your resources.

Comment: Replace `extends cdk.Stack` with `extends Construct`. 
I am referring to the code example in the question - your class is not abstracting anything.

Comment: This does seem to help thank you, though `interface ApiGatewayProps extends cdk.StackProps {
    handler: NodejsFunction
    description: string
    apiName: string
    stageName: string
    deploy: boolean
}` interface should also extend Construct or cdk.StackProps is fine?

Comment: It doesn't have to extend anything.

Comment: Looks like I have achieved what I want but now during deployment I am getting this weird error which I was not getting when I doing it multi stacks `Unable to resolve AWS account to use. It must be either configured when you define your CDK Stack, or through the environment`

Comment: Update the question or open a new one.